# libvlc image save with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, libvlc

I like to create a cv:Mat object image from a video stream image of a libvlc media.

```
sprintf( width, ":vmem-width=%i",VIDEOWIDTH);
sprintf( height,":vmem-height=%i",VIDEOHEIGHT);
sprintf( chroma,":vmem-chroma=%s","RV32");
sprintf( pitch, ":vmem-pitch=%i",VIDEOWIDTH * 4);
libvlc_media_add_option(Media,width);
libvlc_media_add_option(Media,height);
libvlc_media_add_option(Media,chroma);
libvlc_media_add_option(Media,pitch);
libvlc_video_set_callbacks(MediaPlayer,lock,unlock,display,NULL);
```

..and..

```
void * MainHandler::lock(void *data, void **p_pixels){ 
  *p_pixels = (void *)pic;
  return NULL;
} 

void MainHandler::display(void *data, void *id){
   cv::Mat image(VIDEOHEIGHT,VIDEOWIDTH,CV_8UC3,pic);
    ....
}
```

The problem in this obviously the CV_8UC3 because the chroma=RV32 creates 32bit RGB image.
But what is the correct type for this?
I don't see anything like that: http://ninghang.blogspot.hu/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html

Comment: Hmmmm, you yould shouw the sample here instead of just linking :-/ ...

Comment: if it's RV32, try CV_8UC4. or the other way, keep CV_8UC3, and specify RV24 (and VIDEOWIDTH * 3 for pitch)

Comment: Thank you Berak spending time for it. I've tried what you wrote, but I have the same result. The image looks like this: http://tinypic.com/r/2q03ltd/8  On the other hand the function libvlc_video_take_snapshot(MediaPlayer,0,"aaa/",0,0) saves the image without any problem.